# Relational data fields display in Yii2 Details views

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Table `KHDN` references table `Loaihinh` via foreign key `loaihinh_ten`

**Table `Loaihinh`:**

- ten int identity primary key; //
- loai varchar(100);

**Table `KHDN`:**

- ...fields
- loaihinh_ten: foreign key references Loaihinh(ten)

What should i do if i want to show `Loaihinh`. `loai` instead of the foreign key `loaihinh_ten` in khdn/views.php **Yii2**:

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model common\models\Khdn */
?>
<div class="khdn-view">

    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'ten:ntext',
            'chudautu:ntext',
            'ngaybatdau:ntext',
            'ngayhoanthanh:ntext',
            'giatri:ntext',
            'trangthai_ten',
            'diachi:ntext',
            'ghichu:ntext',
            'loaihinh_ten',
        ],
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

thanks you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$model->relationName->fieldName
```

Example:

```
 /**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
 public function getLoaihinh()
{
    return $this->hasOne(KHDN::className(), ['id' => 
      'loaihinh_ten']);
}
```

Then use the following relation in View:

```
 $model->loaihinh->loai;
```

Comment: where do you put "$model->loaihinh->loai;" into?

Comment: It would automatically created by gii for you both the model.

Comment: i know! but i want to ask you where you put it into views.php, i have relation function like  your example in model khdn,php, but my view still show foreign key, so worry :(

Comment: Use like this in view [
                'label' => 'View',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->loaihinh->loai;
                },
            ],

Answer (score 0):

There are many method of doing this things. you can use any of the following methods for this problem.

you need not to use joinWith method for this you can get that relation data any where in your program just using

> $model->relation_name_decleared_in_model

below is the sample code that is use a

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'attribute' => 'type',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return  \app\models\BlockType::getConstantMessage($model->type);
            },
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
            'header' => 'POSITION',
            'attribute' => 'position',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'access',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return  \app\components\Helper::ACCESS[$model->access];
            },
        ],
        'some_attribute',
        [
           'attribute' => 'other_relation',
           'value' => 'model.relation.column'
         ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'Page',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return  $model->page->pageContent->name;
            },
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```